# VB.NET WinForm TabControl

Tags: .net, vb.net, tabs, controls

I'm working on a project that requires tabs. I hate the look of the default VB.NET tabcontrol. Basically I wanted the tabcontrol with solid colors and the tab headers be bigger.

So the requirements were:

-Tab heads must be bigger in height and with
-Tab head text must have padding (be centered)
-Tab heads must be a solid color and have a solid hover color.
-Tabs must be able to be hidden.

Now, I found a custom tab control. I used it, but the problem is that the TabHeads do not expand if the text is larger. They are a fixed width. I figured I would use smaller column headers, that is fine.

But after doing work arounds, I realized it might not be the best solution because it has a weird background that overlays the border, which looks sort of weird. When the text is bold, if long enough, touches the edge of the tab, which looks weird. And finally, I can't hide the tabs.

So, I'm wondering if you guys know I can a)Overload the current tab control and simply make the tab heads a solid color, wider and with padded text. or b)Find a custom tab control that does all of this.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D, System.IO
```

'-------------------------------------
'TabControlDesigner
'
'Creator: Eprouvez
'Updated: 6/6/2012
'Date: 6/5/2012
'Version: 1.1.1
'
'Credits to:
'Aeonhack
'mavamaarten
'
'Update:
'Fixed a bug where ColorHook wasn't properly working when the control was created
'--------------------------------------

MustInherit Class TabControlDesigner
    Inherits TabControl

```
Protected G As Graphics
Protected State As MouseState
Protected Coordinates As Point

Enum MouseState As Integer
    None = 0
    Over = 1
    Down = 2
End Enum
```

## Region " Routines "

```
Sub New()
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    DoubleBuffered = True
    SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
    ItemSize = New Size(250, 26)
End Sub

Sub SetState(ByVal current As MouseState)
    State = current
    Invalidate()
End Sub
```

## End Region

## Region " Hooks "

```
Protected MustOverride Sub TabPaint(ByVal Index As Integer)

Protected MustOverride Sub ColorHook()
Protected Overridable Sub PaintHook()
End Sub
```

## End Region

## Region " Properties "

```
Private _InactiveIconOpacity As Integer = 50
Public Property InactiveIconOpacity As Integer
    Get
        Return _InactiveIconOpacity
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If IsNothing(value) Then value = 50
        If value < 0 Then value = 0
        If value > 100 Then value = 100
        _InactiveIconOpacity = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _PanelColor As Color
Public Property PanelColor() As Color
    Get
        Return _PanelColor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _PanelColor = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Items As New Dictionary(Of String, Color)
Property Colors() As Bloom()
    Get
        Dim T As New List(Of Bloom)
        Dim E As Dictionary(Of String, Color).Enumerator = Items.GetEnumerator

        While E.MoveNext
            T.Add(New Bloom(E.Current.Key, E.Current.Value))
        End While

        Return T.ToArray
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Bloom())
        For Each B As Bloom In value
            If Items.ContainsKey(B.Name) Then Items(B.Name) = B.Color
        Next

        InvalidateCustimization()
        ColorHook()
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

Private _Customization As String
Property Customization() As String
    Get
        Return _Customization
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If value = _Customization Then Return

        Dim Data As Byte()
        Dim Items As Bloom() = Colors

        Try
            Data = Convert.FromBase64String(value)
            For I As Integer = 0 To Items.Length - 1
                Items(I).Color = Color.FromArgb(BitConverter.ToInt32(Data, I * 4))
            Next
        Catch
            Return
        End Try

        _Customization = value

        Colors = Items
        ColorHook()
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

## End Region

## Region " Property Helpers "

```
'Credits to Aeonhack
Protected Function GetPen(ByVal name As String) As Pen
    Return New Pen(Items(name))
End Function
Protected Function GetPen(ByVal name As String, ByVal width As Single) As Pen
    Return New Pen(Items(name), width)
End Function
Protected Function GetBrush(ByVal name As String) As SolidBrush
    Return New SolidBrush(Items(name))
End Function
Protected Function GetColor(ByVal name As String) As Color
    Return Items(name)
End Function
Protected Sub SetColor(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As Color)
    If Items.ContainsKey(name) Then Items(name) = value Else Items.Add(name, value)
End Sub
Protected Sub SetColor(ByVal name As String, ByVal r As Byte, ByVal g As Byte, ByVal b As Byte)
    SetColor(name, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))
End Sub
Protected Sub SetColor(ByVal name As String, ByVal a As Byte, ByVal r As Byte, ByVal g As Byte, ByVal b As Byte)
    SetColor(name, Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b))
End Sub
Protected Sub SetColor(ByVal name As String, ByVal a As Byte, ByVal value As Color)
    SetColor(name, Color.FromArgb(a, value))
End Sub
Private Sub InvalidateCustimization()
    Dim M As New MemoryStream(Items.Count * 4)

    For Each B As Bloom In Colors
        M.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(B.Color.ToArgb), 0, 4)
    Next

    M.Close()
    _Customization = Convert.ToBase64String(M.ToArray)
End Sub
```

## End Region

## Region " Drawing Methods "

```
Function Measure(ByVal Text As String) As SizeF
    Return G.MeasureString(Text, Font)
End Function
Function Measure(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Font As Font) As SizeF
    Return G.MeasureString(Text, Font)
End Function
Function Center(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Area As Rectangle) As Point
    Return Center(Text, Font, Area)
End Function
Function Center(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Font As Font, ByVal Area As Rectangle) As Point
    Return Center(Text, Font, Area, 0, 0)
End Function
Function Center(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Font As Font, ByVal Area As Rectangle, ByVal XOffset As Integer, ByVal YOffset As Integer) As Point
    Dim M = Measure(Text, Font)
    Return New Point(CInt(Area.X + Area.Width / 2 - M.Width / 2) + XOffset, CInt(Area.Y + Area.Height / 2 - M.Height / 2) + YOffset)
End Function
Function ToPen(ByVal color As Color) As Pen
    Return New Pen(color)
End Function
Function ToPen(ByVal color As Color, ByVal width As Single) As Pen
    Return New Pen(color, width)
End Function
Function ToBrush(ByVal color As Color) As Brush
    Return New SolidBrush(color)
End Function
Function RGB(ByVal Red As Integer, ByVal Green As Integer, ByVal Blue As Integer) As Color
    Return Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
Function ARGB(ByVal Alpha As Integer, ByVal color As Color) As Color
    Return color.FromArgb(Alpha, color)
End Function
Function ARGB(ByVal Alpha As Integer, ByVal Red As Integer, ByVal Green As Integer, ByVal Blue As Integer) As Color
    Return Color.FromArgb(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)
End Function
Function Shrink(ByVal rectangle As Rectangle, ByVal Offset As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return Shrink(rectangle, Offset, True)
End Function
Function Shrink(ByVal rectangle As Rectangle, ByVal Offset As Integer, ByVal CenterPoint As Boolean) As Rectangle
    Dim O = If(CenterPoint = True, Offset, 0)
    Dim R = New Rectangle(rectangle.X + O, rectangle.Y + O, rectangle.Width - Offset * 2, rectangle.Height - Offset * 2)
    Return R
End Function
Function Enlarge(ByVal rectangle As Rectangle, ByVal Offset As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return Enlarge(rectangle, Offset, True)
End Function
Function Enlarge(ByVal rectangle As Rectangle, ByVal Offset As Integer, ByVal CenterPoint As Boolean) As Rectangle
    Dim O = If(CenterPoint = True, Offset, 0)
    Dim R = New Rectangle(rectangle.X - O, rectangle.Y - O, rectangle.Width + Offset * 2, rectangle.Height + Offset * 2)
    Return R
End Function
Function ImageOpacity(ByVal Image As Bitmap, ByVal Opacity As Single) As Image
    Dim Result As New Bitmap(Image.Width, Image.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    With Image
        Opacity = Math.Min(Opacity, 100)
        Using Attributes As New Imaging.ImageAttributes
            Dim Matrix As New Imaging.ColorMatrix
            Matrix.Matrix33 = Opacity / 100.0F
            Attributes.SetColorMatrix(Matrix)
            Dim Points() As PointF = {New Point(0, 0), New Point(.Width, 0), New Point(0, .Height)}
            Using I As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Result)
                I.Clear(Color.Transparent)
                I.DrawImage(Image, Points, New RectangleF(Point.Empty, .Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel, Attributes)
            End Using
        End Using
    End With
    Return Result
End Function
```

## End Region

## Region " Override Methods "

```
Protected Overrides Sub CreateHandle()
    MyBase.CreateHandle()
    MyBase.DoubleBuffered = True
    InvalidateCustimization()
    ColorHook()
    SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ColorHook()
    MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    SetState(MouseState.Over)
    MyBase.OnMouseHover(e)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    SetState(MouseState.None)
    For I As Integer = 0 To TabPages.Count - 1
        If TabPages(I).DisplayRectangle.Contains(Coordinates) Then
            MyBase.Invalidate()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MyBase.OnMouseHover(e)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Coordinates = e.Location
    For I As Integer = 0 To TabPages.Count - 1
        If TabPages(I).DisplayRectangle.Contains(Coordinates) Then
            MyBase.Invalidate()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    G = e.Graphics

    If Not IsNothing(_PanelColor) Then G.FillRectangle(ToBrush(_PanelColor), e.ClipRectangle)

    PaintHook()

    For I As Integer = 0 To TabPages.Count - 1
        TabPaint(I)
    Next
End Sub
```

## End Region

End Class

Class Bloom

```
Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Color As Color)
    _Name = Name
    _Value = Color
End Sub
Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Red As Integer, ByVal Green As Integer, ByVal Blue As Integer)
    _Name = Name
    _Value = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Sub
Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Alpha As Integer, ByVal Red As Integer, ByVal Green As Integer, ByVal Blue As Integer)
    _Name = Name
    _Value = Color.FromArgb(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue)
End Sub

Private _Name As String
Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
End Property

Private _Value As Color
Public Property Color() As Color
    Get
        Return _Value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _Value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Class BlueTabControl
    Inherits TabControlDesigner

```
Private C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6 As Color
Private L1, L2 As LinearGradientBrush

Sub New()
    C1 = Color.WhiteSmoke 'Panel Color
    C2 = RGB(13, 55, 110) 'Line Color
    C3 = RGB(148, 212, 255) 'Highlight
    C4 = RGB(214, 245, 255) 'Unselected Tab #1
    C5 = Color.WhiteSmoke 'Unselected Tab #2
    C6 = RGB(13, 55, 110) 'Tab Line

    Alignment = TabAlignment.Top
    Font = New Font("Verdana", 8S)
    ItemSize = New Size(130, 30)
    PanelColor = Color.Transparent

    For I As Integer = 0 To TabPages.Count - 1
        TabPages(I).BackColor = C1
    Next

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub TabPaint(ByVal e As Integer)
    Dim Text = TabPages(e).Text
    Dim Tab = GetTabRect(e)
    Dim Temp = New Rectangle(Tab.X + 1, Tab.Y + 1, Tab.Width - 6, Tab.Height + If(SelectedIndex = e, 1, 0))
    Dim Highlight = New Rectangle(Temp.X, Temp.Y, Temp.Width, 10)
    Dim Outline = New Point() {New Point(Temp.X, Temp.Bottom), New Point(Temp.X, Temp.Top), New Point(Temp.Right, Temp.Top), New Point(Temp.Right, Temp.Bottom)}

    L1 = New LinearGradientBrush(Highlight, C3, C3, 90S)
    L2 = New LinearGradientBrush(Temp, C5, C5, 90S)

    If SelectedIndex = e Then
        Try : TabPages(e).BackColor = C1 : Catch : End Try
        G.FillRectangle(ToBrush(C1), Temp)
    ElseIf State = MouseState.Over AndAlso Temp.Contains(Coordinates) Then
        G.FillRectangle(L1, Temp)
    Else
        G.FillRectangle(L2, Temp)
    End If

    G.DrawLines(ToPen(C2), Outline)
    If SelectedIndex = e Then
        G.DrawString(Text, New Font("Verdana", 8S, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, Center(Text, Font, Temp, 0, 0))
    Else
        G.DrawString(Text, New Font("Verdana", 8S), Brushes.Black, Center(Text, Font, Temp, 0, 0))
    End If

End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub PaintHook()
    Dim Outline = New Point() {New Point(ClientRectangle.X + 3, ClientRectangle.Y + 34), _
                               New Point(ClientRectangle.X + 3, ClientRectangle.Bottom - 4), _
                               New Point(ClientRectangle.Right - 4, ClientRectangle.Bottom - 4), _
                               New Point(ClientRectangle.Right - 4, ClientRectangle.Top + 34)}
    G.DrawLines(ToPen(C6), Outline)
    G.DrawLine(ToPen(C6), 4, 33, Width - 4, 33)
End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub ColorHook()

End Sub

Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'BlueTabControl
    '
    Me.Colors = New ResourcesManagement.Bloom(-1) {}
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Also I was wondering if it is possible to have one tab aligned to the far right and all the others aligned to the far left. The idea is that I want a tab for preferences, and I there to be clear visual separation for it.

Comment: You will continue to **WONDER** since none of use can possibly answer this question without seeing any **CODE**...

Comment: I'm not sure how to add code so I added both classes. But what I was asking was to learn how to paint my own tab (with the requirements I have), or a custom tab tool that already is made that will fulfill my needs. But if you want to help with existing code that's even better.

Answer (score 1):

> Find a custom tab control that does all of this.

Here's [page](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm) with source code on customizing tab controls

Comment: Well the reason I posted this question is to see if experienced people could give me a link to a tab control that does all of it or explain how. I've read tutorials, and they are usually doing more complex stuff than I require.

Comment: It requires a lot of on paint to custom draw your tabs; I have done it. You need to research the OnPaint to get what you need.

Comment: Is it possible you could help me by going into a little more detail with context to what I need? Because the project I am using it for is due very soon. I'd like to not worry about the GUI asap.